# How to put an Ad BannerView to keep in all the views from a TabBar app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, adbannerview

I'm making a Tab Bar application. It has 3 ViewControllers. I learned how to put a working AdBannerView (because I'm kind of a newbie in this), so I put it on the FirstViewController. But then I realized that I want the ad to be present in all the 3 view controllers, not just on the first. So, I'm wondering if I can put the AdBannerView in like the MainWindow.xib or do I have to put one AdBannerView in each ViewController?

Thanks a lot if you can help me with this!

Answer (score 3):

Apple have a technical note on this topic - Technical Note TN2286: Implementing a Shared iAd Banner.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2286/_index.html

Answer (score 3):

The iAdSuite sample code shows how to deal with a BannerView in a tabbed application.

[iAdSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html)